# How to run tests written using jasmine for typescript (angular 2)?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, angular2-testing

I have written unit tests using jasmine framework for angular 2 typescript application. I have not generated project using angular-cli. I installed jasmine and wrote the unit testing for angular component. How do I run this **spec.ts** ? I followed this https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm and try to configure my project to run the tests. But this works only for spec.js test files. I tried with karma and did not work. How to setup the test environment to run tests written for typescript using jasmine?

Comment: compile them into javascript

Comment: @Maximus The jasmine framework do not compile them into javascript? I should write  a script for it?

Comment: I've added [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44503954/2545680), check it

Answer (score 1):

To get your `typescript` files compiled into `javascript`, use `tsc` compiler. Install it by running

```
$ npm i typescript
$ npm i typescript -g
```

And initialize `tsconfig.json`:

```
$ tsc --init
```

Now you can compile your files by simply running `tsc` in the project directory.

`jasmine-npm` specifies that you should run your tests by executing `jasmine`. So you can add the following to the `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "tsc && jasmine"
  },
```

and execute tests by simply running:

```
$ npm test
```

Comment: I tried but I get this error after compiling typescript to javascript `import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

Comment: I ran into the same issue, to solve it ensure that in the tsconfig.json "module": "commonjs"